# Do capacitors limit maximum current in a circuit?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, circuit-analysis, power-electronics

Do capacitors limit maximum current in a circuit when used after a rectifier? If yes, what's the formula for that maximum current?

Comment: Draw a schematic, there's nothing about a cap after a rectifier that limits current.

Comment: Imagine this circuit: AC mains to transformer to rectifier to capacitor (for filtering). My question is does that capacitor limits maximum current in whatever circuit that comes after it?

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Re-read ALL of my first comment. It is still all correct, including the need for a schematic. It may be that when you draw 'the circuit that comes after it', you'll be able to get answers to your question. Hit the edit button under your post, and then hit the resistor/capacitor symbol to bring up the schematic editor. Drawing schematics is a very important skill in engineering, and drawing them with this tool on this site is a very important way of communicating questions here. As it is, your question is nonsense, because ... re-read my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

i = C*(dv/dt), ignoring ESR and inductance.

If your rectified voltage is sinusoidal in shape when the diode is conducting you can differentiate the sine wave and calculate the maximum current.

Comment: What about the computation of inrush current when the capacitor is uncharged and follows a diode? The computation of dv/dt is at least slightly more interesting...

Comment: @jonk Yes, that's the non-repetitive current surge (limited by source impedance, ESR, diode etc), but I think this is a homework problem where the student is expected to do a bit of simple arithmetic to calculate the peak repetitive current.

Comment: Maybe. But the OP's "... in whatever circuit that comes after it..." makes me continue to wonder.